# ContentDocument Parent Object ID How to associate

Tags: contentversion, contentdocument

I'm trying to associate some attachment documents with their Parent object,
How should I do this?

```
public static void  renameFileNameForRelevePromotion(List<ContentVersion> listFiles){
        if(listFiles != null && !listFiles.isEmpty()){
            Map<Id, List<ContentVersion>> filesByParentId = new Map<Id, List<ContentVersion>>();
            for(ContentVersion conVer : listFiles){
                List<ContentVersion> files;
                // Get the ContentDocumentId from ContentVersion
               conVer = [select ContentDocumentId from ContentVersion where id = :conVer.id];
               Id theContentDocumentId = conVer.ContentDocumentId;
               //Create ContentDocumentLink
               Releve_Promotion__c rel = 
               ContentDocumentLink contentlinkprom = new ContentDocumentLink(
                            ContentDocumentId = theContentDocumentId,
                            LinkedEntityId = Releve_Promotion__c.Id,
                            ShareType = 'V',
                            Visibility = 'AllUsers'
                );
              insert contentlinkprom;
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete - what is `Releve_Promotion__c rel = `?

Answer (score 0):

This is the class which needs to rename the files

```
public static void renameFileNameForRelevePromotion(List<ContentVersion> listFiles){

        if(listFiles != null && !listFiles.isEmpty()){
            Map<Id, List<ContentVersion>> filesByParentId = new Map<Id, List<ContentVersion>>();
            for(ContentVersion conVer : listFiles){
                List<ContentVersion> files;
                // Get the ContentDocumentId from ContentVersion
                  Id conVerId = conVer.ContentDocumentId;
               ContentDocumentLink contlink = [SELECT LinkedEntityId from ContentDocumentLink 
                                               where ContentDocumentId=:conVerId];
               Id contentParentId = contlink.LinkedEntityId;

              if(filesByParentId.containsKey(contentParentId)){
                    files = filesByParentId.get(contentParentId);
              }
                else {
                    files = new List<ContentVersion>();
                }
                files.add(conVer);
                filesByParentId.put(contentParentId, files);
            }

            if(!filesByParentId.isEmpty()){
                List<Id> listIds = new List<Id>(filesByParentId.keySet());
                Map<Id, Releve_Promotion__C> relPromos = new Map<Id, Releve_Promotion__C>(
                    [SELECT Id, Name, Promotion__r.Name, Client__r.Name FROM Releve_Promotion__c WHERE Id in:listIds]);

                Map<Id, Releve_Promo_pirate__c> relPromoPirates = new Map<Id, Releve_Promo_pirate__c>(
                    [SELECT Id, Name, Promotion_pirate__r.Name,Client__r.Name FROM Releve_Promo_pirate__c WHERE Id in:listIds]);

                for(ContentVersion content : listFiles){
                    List<String> splitStrList = content.Title.Split('\\.');
                    String fileExtension = splitStrList[1];

                    Id contentId = [select Id, ContentDocumentId from ContentVersion 
                                  where id = :content.id].ContentDocumentId;
                    ContentDocumentLink contlinkprom = [SELECT LinkedEntityId from ContentDocumentLink 
                                                        where ContentDocumentId=:contentId];
                    Id contentParentIdd = contlinkprom.LinkedEntityId;

                    // Releve Promotion
                    if(relPromos.containsKey(contentParentIdd)){
                        Releve_Promotion__C rp = relPromos.get(contentParentIdd);
                        content.Title = rp.Promotion__r.Name + '_' + rp.Client__r.Name +'_'+ UserInfo.getName() +'_'+ String.valueOf(System.now()) + '.'+ fileExtension;
                    }
                    // Releve Promotion Pirate
                    if(relPromoPirates.containsKey(contentParentIdd)){
                        Releve_Promo_pirate__c rpp = relPromoPirates.get(contentParentIdd);
                        content.Title = rpp.Promotion_pirate__r.Name + '_'+ rpp.Client__r.Name +'_'+ UserInfo.getName() +'_'+ String.valueOf(System.now()) +'.'+ fileExtension;
                }
            }

        }
    }
 }

}
```